# Is 5 a maximum number of buildings in Stone Age?

Tags: stone-age

On the player board there are 3 spaces for tools. Player can't have more than 3 tools at the same time (permanent tools). There are 5 spaces for buildings. Therefore, I assumed 5 is a limit of huts a player might own. Is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no limit to the number of huts a player can have. The space on the board is simply done that way for design; you do not have to put 1 hut in each space.

From the [rulebook](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Stone_Age.pdf), page 7:

> The player places the acquired building on one of the corresponding spaces of their
>   board. Once a player has more than 5 buildings, he stacks them on these spaces.

Comment: Wow, then this design can really be confusing. There is no point in having those spaces on the player board at all, one would be sufficient and would avoid confusion. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @beam022 I agree. Plus, it is not made clear and obvious in the rulebook, you have to find that one sentence hidden there.

Comment: That paragraph reads something like "This is the authoritative way to do it. Actually, **** it, just put them wherever. I'm not a cop."